# sql script group by help needed

Tags: mysql

I have sql script that needed further tweaking to produce a simpler report as shown below. I am looking for the results to be grouped on username.

> userName, weeknum, and #of wins

```
select 
  p.userID,
  s.gameID,
  p.pickID,
  u.userName,
  s.weekNum,
  s.homeID, 
  s.homeScore, 
  s.visitorID, 
  s.visitorScore
from nflp_picks p 
inner join nflp_users u
  on p.userID = u.userID 
inner join nflp_schedule s 
  on p.gameID = s.gameID 
where s.weekNum = 6 
  and u.userName <> 'admin' 
order by p.userID, s.gameTimeEastern, s.gameID;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make you current query as derived table, then do like this:

```
SELECT userName, 
        weeknum,
        SUM(CASE WHEN pickID=homeID 
            AND homeScore > visitorScore THEN 1
            WHEN pickID=visitorID 
            AND visitorScore > homeScore THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END) AS "# of wins"
  FROM
(SELECT 
  p.userID,
  s.gameID,
  p.pickID,
  u.userName,
  s.weekNum,
  s.homeID, 
  s.homeScore, 
  s.visitorID, 
  s.visitorScore
FROM nflp_picks p 
INNER JOIN nflp_users u
  ON p.userID = u.userID 
INNER JOIN nflp_schedule s 
  ON p.gameID = s.gameID 
WHERE s.weekNum = 6
  AND u.userName <> 'admin' 
ORDER BY p.userID, s.gameTimeEastern, s.gameID) a
  GROUP BY userName, weeknum;
```

`SUM()` over `CASE` expression checking if `pickID` value is the same as the winning team.

[Here's a trimmed down fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/TCLik-aU)